# Which loss function and metrics to use for multi-label classification with very high ratio of negatives to positives?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, multilabel-classification, vgg-net

I am training a multi-label classification model for detecting attributes of clothes. I am using transfer learning in Keras, retraining the last few layers of the vgg-19 model.

The total number of attributes is 1000 and about 99% of them are 0s. Metrics like accuracy, precision, recall, etc., all fail, as the model can predict all zeroes and still achieve a very high score. Binary cross-entropy, hamming loss, etc., haven't worked in the case of loss functions.

I am using the deep fashion dataset.

So, which metrics and loss functions can I use to measure my model correctly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What hassan has suggested is not correct - 
Categorical Cross-Entropy loss or Softmax Loss is a *Softmax activation* plus a Cross-Entropy loss. If we use this loss, we will train a CNN to output a probability over the C classes for each image. It is used for **multi-class classification**.

What you want is multi-label classification, so you will use **Binary Cross-Entropy Loss** or Sigmoid Cross-Entropy loss. It is a *Sigmoid activation* plus a Cross-Entropy loss. Unlike Softmax loss it is independent for each vector component (class), meaning that the loss computed for every CNN output vector component is not affected by other component values. That’s why it is used for multi-label classification, where the insight of an element belonging to a certain class should not influence the decision for another class.

Now for handling class imbalance, you can use weighted Sigmoid Cross-Entropy loss. So you will penalize for wrong prediction based on the number/ratio of positive examples.

Comment: really. softmax is for multiclass classification (Figure10 here - https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-4 - )... thanks for advice about multi-label classification in imbalanced data

Comment: Just a question: in multi-class classification with softmax, in backprop and optimization stage, we try to update the weights in order to maximize the estimated class probability and also minimize the wrong estimation probability. So, if we have several true y (like [1,0,0,0,1,1]) for any sample, during the backprop and optimization, we manipulate the weights for true also classes to minimize the probability. Is that true?

Comment: @MahdiAmrollahi Yes

Answer (score 9):

Actually you should use `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`.
It not only for multi label classification and also has a `pos_weight` can pay much attention at the positive classes as you would expected.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-class and binary-class classification determine the number of output units, i.e. the number of neurons in the final layer.
Multi-label and single-Label determines which choice of activation function for the final layer and loss function you should use.
For single-label, the standard choice is Softmax with categorical cross-entropy; for multi-label, switch to Sigmoid activations with binary cross-entropy.

Categorical Cross-Entropy:

[image]

Binary Cross-Entropy:

[image]

`C` is the number of classes, and `m` is the number of examples in the current mini-batch. `L` is the loss function and `J` is the cost function. You can also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320165/179078).
In the loss function, you are iterating over different classes. In the cost function, you are iterating over the examples in the current mini-batch.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this github. They have binary, multi-class, multi-labels and also options to enforce model to learn close to 0 and 1 or simply learn probability.

https://github.com/monkeyDemon/AI-Toolbox/blob/master/computer_vision/image_classification_keras/loss_function/focal_loss.py

Steve

Comment: For those confused, focal loss is a custom loss function that results in 'good' predictions having less impact on overall loss and results in 'bad' predictions having about the same impact as regular loss functions. For sparse outputs, this means that you force the network to confront what you're getting wrong, while mostly ignoring what it gets right (the random guessing to the majority output).

Answer (score -1):

I have been in a simialr situation like yours

you can use softmax activation function in the output layer with categorical_crossentropy to check other metrics such as precision, recall and f1 score you can use the sklearn library as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_pred = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_bool))
```

as for the training stage as far as know there is the accuracy metric as follows

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy'
              , metrics=['acc'], optimizer='adam')
```

if it helps you, you can plot the training history for the loss and accuracy of your training stage using matplotlib as follows :

```
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=24, epochs=1000, verbose=2,
                 callbacks=[checkpoint],
                 validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid)

                 )
# Plot training & validation accuracy values
plt.plot(hist.history['acc'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```